# Postgresql Convert date with timestamp with date only while exporting

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm using Postgres to save my data with date.

but the date it is saving in this format `14:42:41.021+05:30`

now while exporting I want to convert it into a date only format. Please help.

Comment: Exporting to what? Have you tried anything to achieve it?

Comment: I'm exporting that table. I want to convert that field with date only.

Comment: Do you mean, from one table to another table?

Comment: No, I'm exporting it into an excel. I'm able to export but I want dates in excel my sheet not timestamp

Comment: `14:42:41.021+05:30` - > Are you sure that this data consists a specific date ie. dd mm yyyy ?

Comment: I'm not sure but its data type is 'date with timestamp'

Comment: In fact, aforementioned data doesn't have a date. Double check your data

Comment: There is no `date with timestamp` type in Postgres. It's either `date` or `timestamp`. Do you maybe mean `timestamp with time zone`?

Comment: from his example its `time with timezone` which makes it worst for OP I suppose

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your column type of date is timestamp in postgres. If it is so, you can get the only date without time as below

```
SELECT to_char(date_column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DAY') FROM Table
```

There are other variants too, like

```
SELECT to_char(date_column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM Table
SELECT to_char(date_column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DY') FROM Table
SELECT to_char(date_column_name, 'YYYY-Month') FROM Table
```